# Variables in Woo Commerce Ajax Mini Cart plugin sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

any idea on how to insert a drop-down field for product variables into the cart side bar of a plugin called "Woo commerce Ajax Mini Cart?

Currently it only shows the quantity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-update-variations-in-cart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-update-variations-in-cart/)

I don't know if it is compatible with Woo commerce Ajax Mini Cart but it works great for the cart page.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply!

Comment: I tried it but didn't work with the Ajax Mini Cart plugin. Cheers!